# ubuntu 12.04 Wireless problem hp pavilion

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, hp

I'm not able to enable Wireless using the hardware switch -f12- on my HP Pavilion dv6-7080-se.

the Enable Wireless option is greyd out so I cannot enable it.

while starting ubuntu when i press f12 -which starts wifi drive- for a login time the wifi works.

The results of `iwconfig` for my system are as follows

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

eth1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

the result of `rfkill list all` for my system is as follows
1

```
: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
5: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
6: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

here is my `sudo lshw -C network` result.

```
 *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 01
       serial: 08:ed:b9:26:06:81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.20.155.1 (r326264) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:19 memory:d4500000-d4503fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 08:2e:5f:73:2a:e2
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d4404000-d4404fff memory:d4400000-d4403fff
```

`lspci -vnn | grep Network` showed:

```
0a:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`sudo rfkill unblock all`

then

`sudo ifconfig eth1 up`

It should turn you wifi on.

Comment: nah it didn't the point is after typing `sudo rfkill unblock all

` it still the same as in post
`: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
5: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
6: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no`

Comment: Broadcom wirless does not work properly on Ubuntu. [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx) post may help you. Also make sure that  you have not  turned off you wireless from BIOS menu.

Answer (score 2):

In the Additional Drivers application, check for any drivers pertaining to STA and disable them.

Open Terminal and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove b43-fwcutter broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source firmware-b43-installer firmware-b43-lpphy-installer firmware-b43legacy-installer bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Now, enter the following commands:

```
echo "blacklist bcma" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
echo "blacklist brcm80211" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Reboot Ubuntu.

Open Terminal again and enter the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source broadcom-sta-common broadcom-sta-source firmware-b43-installer
```

After the package installation is complete, reboot.

Open Additional Drivers.

Enable the Broadcom STA driver.

Your Wifi should now be active and functional.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem with HP Pavilion dv5 and Mint 16 Petra. What worked for me was to reset BIOS to factory defaults. There appears to be no other way to access wifi in BIOS and touching wifi antenna to turn it to blue on state at boot did not work although it works for windows.